# CakePHP send form depending on data

Tags: forms, cakephp, cakephp-model

Hello I'm fairly new to cakephp, I've just done two tutorials hehehe but now I'm working on it and I have a register form in which I register a user, But depending on the type of the user, more models will be shown and sent to the controller to register it. I was wondering which is the best practice to do this? Do it in separate forms, or sending the information depending on the user type?

Here is my View:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('type' => 'file')); ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo __('Add User'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->file('User.user_image');
        echo $this->Form->input('User.name', array( 'label' => 'Nombre' ));
        echo $this->Form->input('User.last_name', array( 'label' => 'Apellidos' ));
        echo $this->Form->input('User.email', array( 'label' => 'E-Mail' ));
        echo $this->Form->input('User.password', array( 'label' => 'Contraseña' ));
        echo $this->Form->input('User.phone', array( 'label' => 'Telefono' ));
        //echo $this->Form->input('created_ip_connection');
        //echo $this->Form->input('last_ip_connection');
        echo $this->Form->input('User.group_id', array('empty' => 'Elige un rol',  'label' => 'Rol de Usuario'));
    ?>
    <div style="display: none;" id="companyAdd">
        <legend><?php echo __('Datos de Compañia'); ?></legend>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('Address.exterior_number', array( 'label' => 'Numero Exterior' ));
            echo $this->Form->input('Address.internal_number', array( 'label' => 'Numero Interior' ));
            echo $this->Form->input('Address.street', array( 'label' => 'Calle' ));
            echo $this->Form->input('Address.suburby', array( 'label' => 'Colonia' ));
            echo $this->Form->input('Address.country_id', array('empty' => 'Selecciona País', 'label' => 'Pais'));
            echo $this->Form->input('Address.state_id', array('empty' => 'Selecciona País', 'label' => 'Estado'));
            echo $this->Form->input('Address.city_id', array('empty' => 'Selecciona Estado', 'label' => 'Municipio'));
            echo $this->Form->input('Company.name', array( 'label' => 'Nombre de Compañia' ));
            echo $this->Form->input('Company.description', array( 'label' => 'Descripción de Compañia' ));
            echo $this->Form->input('Company.bank_acc', array( 'label' => 'Cuenta de Banco' ));
            echo $this->Form->input('Company.rfc', array( 'label' => 'RFC' ));
        ?>
    </div>
    <div style="display: none;" id="userAdd">
        <legend><?php echo __('Datos de Comprador/Proveedor'); ?></legend>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('Buyer.company_id', array('empty' => 'Elige Comapñia', 'label' => 'Compañia'));
        ?>
    </div>
</fieldset>

<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Registrar')); ?>
```

In this if the user has a certain group_id the companyAdd div will be visible for editing, if its another the userAdd div will be shown and if hes admin only the info of the user will be sent. When I try to submit this, the form wont let me cause the inputs for company and user are necessary. How can I control which data is sent depending on the group_id of the user?

The models goes as follow

User hasOne Buyer
User hasOne Provider(NormalUsers)
User hasOne Comapny

By the way Comapny has an address too thats why Address is another model

In the controller I'm thinking over use saveAll or a save per model sent.

Any suggestions or tutorials I can see how this is make ? or Best practices?

Comment: I would create separate [elements](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#elements) for each registration scenario. Then let step 1 in the process be to let the user select (or determine for them?) what kind of registration it is and load the proper element using AJAX.

Comment: I asked another question which answered this one as well. Please refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28351607/cakephp-use-saveall-and-specify-which-models-only?noredirect=1#comment45051858_28351607) for the answer to this one :P