# Cakephp use saveAll and specify which models only

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-model

Im new to relatively new to cakephp, right now I'm trying to use saveall() and save individual models depending on the role the user chose for the register.

Here is my View:

```
    <?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('type' => 'file')); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Add User'); ?></legend>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->file('User.user_image');
            echo $this->Form->input('User.name', array( 'label' => 'Nombre'));
            echo $this->Form->input('User.last_name', array( 'label' => 'Apellidos' ));
            echo $this->Form->input('User.email', array( 'label' => 'E-Mail' ));
            echo $this->Form->input('User.password', array( 'label' => 'Contraseña' ));
            echo $this->Form->input('User.phone', array( 'label' => 'Telefono' ));
            //echo $this->Form->input('created_ip_connection');
            //echo $this->Form->input('last_ip_connection'); 
            echo $this->Form->input('User.group_id', array('empty' => 'Elige un rol',  'label' => 'Rol de Usuario'));
        ?>
        <div style="display: none;" id="companyAdd">
            <legend><?php echo __('Datos de Compañia'); ?></legend>
            <?php
                echo $this->Form->input('Address.exterior_number', array( 'label' => 'Numero Exterior', 'required' => false ));
                echo $this->Form->input('Address.internal_number', array( 'label' => 'Numero Interior', 'required' => false ));
                echo $this->Form->input('Address.street', array( 'label' => 'Calle', 'required' => false ));
                echo $this->Form->input('Address.suburby', array( 'label' => 'Colonia', 'required' => false ));
                echo $this->Form->input('Address.country_id', array('empty' => 'Selecciona País', 'label' => 'Pais', 'required' => false));
                echo $this->Form->input('Address.state_id', array('empty' => 'Selecciona País', 'label' => 'Estado', 'required' => false));
                echo $this->Form->input('Address.city_id', array('empty' => 'Selecciona Estado', 'label' => 'Municipio', 'required' => false));
                echo $this->Form->input('Company.name', array( 'label' => 'Nombre de Compañia', 'required' => false ));
                echo $this->Form->input('Company.description', array( 'label' => 'Descripción de Compañia', 'required' => false ));
                echo $this->Form->input('Company.bank_acc', array( 'label' => 'Cuenta de Banco', 'required' => false ));
                echo $this->Form->input('Company.rfc', array( 'label' => 'RFC', 'required' => false ));
            ?>
        </div>
        <div style="display: none;" id="userAdd">
            <legend><?php echo __('Datos de Comprador/Proveedor'); ?></legend>
            <?php
                echo $this->Form->input('Buyer.company_id', array('empty' => 'Elige Comapñia', 'label' => 'Compañia', 'required' => false));
            ?>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Registrar')); ?>
```

Here is my controller:

```
public function register(){
    $this->layout = 'generalLayout'; 
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if($this->request->data['User']['group_id'] == 1){
            $this->User->create();
            if(!empty($this->data))
            {
                //Check if image has been uploaded
                if(!empty($this->data['User']['user_image']['name']))
                {
                    $file = $this->data['User']['user_image']; //put the data into a var for easy use

                    $ext = substr(strtolower(strrchr($file['name'], '.')), 1); //get the extension
                    $arr_ext = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'); //set allowed extensions

                    //only process if the extension is valid
                    if(in_array($ext, $arr_ext))
                    {
                        //do the actual uploading of the file. First arg is the tmp name, second arg is
                        //where we are putting it
                        $destinationPath = 'images\users\\';
                        $randomCode = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 5, 5);
                        $filename = $this->data['User']['name'].'_'.$randomCode."_".$file['name'];
                        move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT . $destinationPath . $filename);

                        //prepare the filename for database entry
                        $this->request->data['User']['user_image'] = $filename;
                    }
                }
                $this->request->data['User']['created_ip_connection'] = $this->request->clientIp();
                $this->request->data['User']['last_ip_connection'] = $this->request->clientIp();
                if ($this->User->saveAll($this->request->data['User'])) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved.'));
                    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'register'));
                } else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
                }
                //now do the save
                //$this->products->save($this->data) ;
            }
        }
        if($this->request->data['User']['group_id'] == 2){
            $this->User->create();
            if(!empty($this->data))
            {
                //Check if image has been uploaded
                if(!empty($this->data['User']['user_image']['name']))
                {
                    $file = $this->data['User']['user_image']; //put the data into a var for easy use

                    $ext = substr(strtolower(strrchr($file['name'], '.')), 1); //get the extension
                    $arr_ext = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'); //set allowed extensions

                    //only process if the extension is valid
                    if(in_array($ext, $arr_ext))
                    {
                        //do the actual uploading of the file. First arg is the tmp name, second arg is
                        //where we are putting it
                        $destinationPath = 'images\users\\';
                        $randomCode = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 5, 5);
                        $filename = $this->data['User']['name'].'_'.$randomCode."_".$file['name'];
                        move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT . $destinationPath . $filename);

                        //prepare the filename for database entry
                        $this->request->data['User']['user_image'] = $filename;
                    }
                }
                $this->request->data['User']['created_ip_connection'] = $this->request->clientIp();
                $this->request->data['User']['last_ip_connection'] = $this->request->clientIp();
                if ($this->User->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved.'));
                    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'register'));
                } else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
                }
                //now do the save
                //$this->products->save($this->data) ;
            }
        }
        if($this->request->data['User']['group_id'] == 3){
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Group 3 Happened'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'register'));
        }
        /*$this->Session->setFlash(__('Nothing Happened'));
        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'register'));*/

    }
    $groups = $this->User->Group->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('groups'));
    $companies = $this->User->Company->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('companies'));
}
```

And my models relations

```
public $hasOne = array(
    'Buyer' => array(
        'className' => 'Buyer',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Company' => array(
        'className' => 'Company',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Provider' => array(
        'className' => 'Provider',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

I want to either send only the information needed (Meaning the models depending on the group chosen.) through the form to the controller. or in the controller use only the models sent to save the models that I want. How could I make this work. saveAll does not work cause Im sending other models with no information through the form as well. How could I make this work ?

Also how do I get the id of the user I just saved?

Comment: Did you try to delete the information you don't want prior to `saveAll`- e.g., `unset($this->request->data['Provider'])` if you don't want the Provider fields?

Comment: You could also unbind the models just before you call saveAll

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out how to do it. I used the [Saving Related Model Data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-hasone-hasmany-belongsto) method. I just use the information I want from the data send by the form depending on the type of the user being created. I left the view and the model untouched. I only changed the controller for the parts of when the group_id is 2(Normal User) and 3(Semi-Admin User). Using the model relations and the information being sent I could use the save() method with each model depending on the information I was given.  Here is the code I hope It helps someone:

```
$this->layout = 'generalLayout'; 
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if($this->request->data['User']['group_id'] == 1){
            $this->User->create();
            if(!empty($this->data))
            {
                //Check if image has been uploaded
                if(!empty($this->data['User']['user_image']['name']))
                {
                    $file = $this->data['User']['user_image']; //put the data into a var for easy use

                    $ext = substr(strtolower(strrchr($file['name'], '.')), 1); //get the extension
                    $arr_ext = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'); //set allowed extensions

                    //only process if the extension is valid
                    if(in_array($ext, $arr_ext))
                    {
                        //do the actual uploading of the file. First arg is the tmp name, second arg is
                        //where we are putting it
                        $destinationPath = 'images\users\\';
                        $randomCode = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 5, 5);
                        $filename = $this->data['User']['name'].'_'.$randomCode."_".$file['name'];
                        move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT . $destinationPath . $filename);

                        //prepare the filename for database entry
                        $this->request->data['User']['user_image'] = $filename;
                    }
                }
                $this->request->data['User']['created_ip_connection'] = $this->request->clientIp();
                $this->request->data['User']['last_ip_connection'] = $this->request->clientIp();
                if ($this->User->saveAll($this->request->data['User'])) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved.'));
                    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'register'));
                } else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
                }
                //now do the save
                //$this->products->save($this->data) ;
            }
        }
        if($this->request->data['User']['group_id'] == 2){
            $this->User->create();
            if(!empty($this->data))
            {
                //Check if image has been uploaded
                if(!empty($this->data['User']['user_image']['name']))
                {
                    $file = $this->data['User']['user_image']; //put the data into a var for easy use

                    $ext = substr(strtolower(strrchr($file['name'], '.')), 1); //get the extension
                    $arr_ext = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'); //set allowed extensions

                    //only process if the extension is valid
                    if(in_array($ext, $arr_ext))
                    {
                        //do the actual uploading of the file. First arg is the tmp name, second arg is
                        //where we are putting it
                        $destinationPath = 'images\users\\';
                        $randomCode = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 5, 5);
                        $filename = $this->data['User']['name'].'_'.$randomCode."_".$file['name'];
                        move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT . $destinationPath . $filename);

                        //prepare the filename for database entry
                        $this->request->data['User']['user_image'] = $filename;
                    }
                }
                $this->request->data['User']['created_ip_connection'] = $this->request->clientIp();
                $this->request->data['User']['last_ip_connection'] = $this->request->clientIp();
                if ($this->User->save($this->request->data['User'])) {
                    //Obtener el Id de user guardado
                    $userId = $this->User->id;
                    $this->request->data['Buyer']['user_id'] = $userId;
                    $this->request->data['Provider'] = $this->request->data['Buyer'];
                    if ($this->User->Buyer->save($this->request->data['Buyer']) && $this->User->Provider->save($this->request->data['Provider'])){
                        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved.'));
                        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'register'));
                    } else {
                        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Buyer or Provider could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
                    }

                } else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
                }
                //now do the save
                //$this->products->save($this->data) ;
            }
        }
        if($this->request->data['User']['group_id'] == 3){
            /*echo print_r($this->request->data);
            return false;*/
            $this->User->create();
            if(!empty($this->data))
            {
                //Check if image has been uploaded
                if(!empty($this->data['User']['user_image']['name']))
                {
                    $file = $this->data['User']['user_image']; //put the data into a var for easy use

                    $ext = substr(strtolower(strrchr($file['name'], '.')), 1); //get the extension
                    $arr_ext = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'); //set allowed extensions

                    //only process if the extension is valid
                    if(in_array($ext, $arr_ext))
                    {
                        //do the actual uploading of the file. First arg is the tmp name, second arg is
                        //where we are putting it
                        $destinationPath = 'images\users\\';
                        $randomCode = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 5, 5);
                        $filename = $this->data['User']['name'].'_'.$randomCode."_".$file['name'];
                        move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT . $destinationPath . $filename);

                        //prepare the filename for database entry
                        $this->request->data['User']['user_image'] = $filename;
                    }
                }
                //Save the user 
                $this->request->data['User']['created_ip_connection'] = $this->request->clientIp();
                $this->request->data['User']['last_ip_connection'] = $this->request->clientIp();
                if ($this->User->save($this->request->data['User'])) {
                    //Get the id of the user I just saved
                    $userId = $this->User->id;
                    if ($this->User->Company->Address->save($this->request->data["Address"])) {
                        $addressId = $this->User->Company->Address->id;
                        $this->request->data['Company']['user_id'] = $userId;
                        $this->request->data['Company']['address_id'] = $addressId;
                        $this->request->data['Company']['permision'] = true;
                        if ($this->User->Company->save($this->request->data["Company"])) {
                            $companyId = $this->User->Company->id;
                            $this->request->data['Buyer']['user_id'] = $userId;
                            $this->request->data['Buyer']['company_id'] = $companyId;
                            $this->request->data['Provider'] = $this->request->data['Buyer'];
                            if ($this->User->Buyer->save($this->request->data['Buyer']) && $this->User->Provider->save($this->request->data['Provider'])){
                                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved.'));
                                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'register'));
                            } else {
                                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Buyer or Provider could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
                            }
                        } else {
                            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The company could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
                        }
                    } else {
                        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Address could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
                }



                //now do the save
                //$this->products->save($this->data) ;
            }
        }
        /*$this->Session->setFlash(__('Nothing Happened'));
        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'register'));*/

    }
    $groups = $this->User->Group->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('groups'));
    $companies = $this->User->Company->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('companies'));
```